# TDateTime LinkError

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I am using C++ Builder and am getting the following errors:

```
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::Internal::Strhlpr::UnicodeFree(System::UnicodeString&)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\9.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|ustring
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::Internal::Strhlpr::UnicodeFromPChar(System::UnicodeString&, char *, bool)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\9.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|ustring
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::Sysutils::StrToDateTime(const System::UnicodeString)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\9.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|datetime
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::Sysutils::StrToDate(const System::UnicodeString)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\9.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|datetime
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::Syncobjs::TInterlocked::Increment(int&)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\9.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|ustring
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::Sysutils::StrToTime(const System::UnicodeString)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\9.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|datetime
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
```

This is my code in main:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

//TDateTime Mine("12/05/1990",TDateTime::TDateTimeFlag::Date);

TDateTime Mine("12/05/1990");

getch();
return 0;
}
```

And I have included 'vcl.h'

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: [titles don't need the tags in them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Borland/Embarcadero tools nowadays, but I would guess you forgot to link to vcle.lib, as linker reports.

It seems that `TDateTime` constructor uses `Sysutils::StrToDateTime()` which is implemented in vcle.lib.

Add vcle.lib to linker settings, and see if it builds. Linker settings can be modified in `Project Options > Linker`

Comment: Where can I find the linker settings?

Comment: As I said, I don't use Borland stuff for ages, but your documentation should tell you. There should be something like Project Settings -> linker, or similar to this.

Comment: OK, I think that I have it working. Just to check, how can I print the value of the variable: TDateTime Mine("12/05/1990")?

Comment: no idea, as I don't use their stuff, but the documentation should help. Also what does it mean print? show it in console? display in the form? In c++ you can print to console with `printf` or `std::cout << ...`. This is actually completely different question.

Comment: Sorry, console. I know how to cout... I just want to check that the linker is working now.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand. If it builds successfully, then linker is working. How will printing the value prove that?

Comment: maybe something like this
`AnsiString s = Mine.DateString();`
`std::cout << s.c_str();`